# WHERE em campo bigint[]

Tags: array, postgresql

Tenho que realizar uma consulta para saber se o código de um grupo esta nas permissões para ver o campo.

```
SELECT *
  FROM callcenter.pausa 
    WHERE habilitado = 1 
     AND permissao_ver::varchar ilike '%1%'
    ORDER BY pausa ASC
```

Resultado:

```
{26,9,10,7,19,2,21,11,17,14,15,6,8,25,24,32,27,28,22,23,13,12,16}
```

Esse array não tem o numero 1 mas o mesmo me retorna dados pois exitem outros numero com o digito 1, preciso que ele verifique certinho que realmente tem o numero 1.

Comment: Se você que quer ele te retorne apenas os dados que sejam o numero um por que esta usando o `like`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rafael,

Você pode utilizar o operador &&, ele compara dois array e se qualquer elemento existir nos dois ele retorna true (como se fosse um "OR").

Assumindo que esse campo permissao_ver seja um bigint[], você pode fazer o comando conforme exemplo:

```
SELECT *
FROM callcenter.pausa 
WHERE habilitado = 1 
AND permissao_ver && '{1}'::bigint[]
ORDER BY pausa ASC
```

Você pode consultar mais detalhes na documentação do postgres: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE